# Adding support of HTTP PATCH

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have an API endpoint to modify a race car, which supports the `PUT` method:

```
PUT /api/racecars/{racecarId}
```

Since PUT must be idempotent it works as a full replacement of an entity:

```
[Route("api/racecars/{racecarId}")]
public class RacecarsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRaceCarsAppService racecarsAppService;

    public RacecarsController (IRaceCarsAppService racecarsAppService)
    {
        this.racecarsAppService = racecarsAppService;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Put(int racecarId, [FromBody] Racecar model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Racecar model is not specified");
        }

        try
        {
            racecarsAppService.Update(racecarId, model.NextServiceDate, model.CrashesCount);

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (DomainRuleViolationException e)
        {
            return Forbidden(e.Message);
        }
    }

    protected IActionResult Forbidden(string errorMessage)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, errorMessage);
    }
}

public class DomainRuleViolationException : Exception
{
    public DomainRuleViolationException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class Racecar
{
    public int RacecarId { get; set; }
    public int CrashesCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime NextServiceDate { get; set; }
}

public interface IRaceCarsAppService 
{
    void Update(int racecarId, DateTime nextServiceDate, int crashesCount);
}
```

However, our customers fairly asked to introduce partial updates for the `racecar` entity. Here is what I've come up with so far. First we need to introduce the Patch model with nulls:

```
public class RacecarPatch
{
    public int RacecarId { get; set; }
    public int? CrashesCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? NextServiceDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the `Patch` method of the controller:

```
    [HttpPatch]
    public IActionResult Patch(int racecarId, [FromBody] RacecarPatch model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Racecar model is not specified");
        }

        try
        {
            if (model.CrashesCount.HasValue)
            {
                racecarsAppService.UpdateCrashesCount(racecarId, model.CrashesCount.Value);
            }

            if (model.NextServiceDate.HasValue)
            {
                racecarsAppService.UpdateNextServiceDate(racecarId, model.UpdateNextServiceDate.Value);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (DomainRuleViolationException e)
        {
            return Forbidden(e.Message);
        }
    }

public interface IRaceCarsAppService 
{
    void Update(int racecarId, DateTime nextServiceDate, int crashesCount);

    void UpdateCrashesCount(int racecarId, int crashesCount);

    void UpdateNextServiceDate(int racecarId, DateTime nextServiceDate);
}
```

I know this is a pretty straightforward approach, so I'd be glad to know if there are any alternative options.